# Issue build endpoint url for Google.Cloud.Vision.V1 .NET

Tags: .net, google-cloud-vision

Tell me please, how to build a URL for the endpoint with Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.
after publishing the model and endpoint.

The address is shown in the examples
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3LlD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn3Ro.png)

When I set the endpoint like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yBIZ.png)

An error occurs when trying to annotate:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g58z.png)

error text: Status(StatusCode="Unimplemented", Detail="The GRPC target is not implemented on the server, host: us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com, method: /google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotator/BatchAnnotateImages.")

I suspect that I am not collecting the address correctly, but I can’t find information on how to collect it correctly so that everything works.
Any help would be very good